# Is there a straightforward way to fit data to a circular/helical curve using sklearn or the ilk?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, model-fitting

I have a lot of raw data that I, as a human, am aware that it follows a circle (and for different datasets, a helix) and I wanted to know if there was a way, using sklearn to fit this data to a circle/helix and if possible derive the parameters required to reconstruct it.

I am completely in the dark and have no idea where to start, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know of scipy curvefit function that would do what you want. You need to define your function depending on parameters and then scipy would find the least squares fit for you.https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Comment: Thanks! I looked into this, but this requires a well-defined function. In the case of a helix, there exists only a parametrized form. My question, I guess, would then be given some data, how can I 'a', 'b' and 'w' such that I could fit it to the following curve : x = a cos(w t), y = a sin(w t), z = b t ?

Comment: Okay, now the question is: do you know of any ordering of those points? Or is it just an unordered set of points that you get your data as?

Comment: The data is technically ordered by time, so yes.

Comment: One other idea I have is that you could project the data by flattening the z axis. Then fit a circle. Once you have the circle and it's centre, you could then calculate the angle (wt) for each point. You will make sure that the ordering is preserved by adding multiples of 2pi. Having done that you can then unflatten the projection by adding a third component equal to some z = bt for some b to be determined by just running a linear regression against the third component and <<time or angle>>.